# как закодировать видео в python?

Tags: python, mp4

можно ли вшить видеофайл mp4 внутрь скрипта python? мне нужно что бы скрипт с видео были одним файлом. я думал, может есть способ закодировать видео в str и хранить как переменную,а потом раскодировать и воспроизвести? или есть другие способы реализовать данную идею?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
data = open("video.mp4", "rb")
bytes = data.read()
```

в переменной bytes хранится закодированное видео. это окозалось проще, чем я думал. оставлю этот вопрос на случай, если кто тоже впадает в ступор